# SignalR TryWebSockets=false and WebSocketServerUrl=null

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, websocket, signalr, .net-4.5

I have just created a new MVC4 WebAPI project, .net 4.5, in Visual Studio 2012. First thing I did was add SignalR from NuGet. I added a hub, and the Application_Start route map, and added some basic javascript to the _layout.cshtml to spin up a connection to my hub. All very basic boilerplate stuff.

Hit f5 to debug in Chrome

Running fiddler, my localhost:19249/signalr/negotiate?_=1373048637010 returns:

```
{
    "Url":"/signalr",
    "ConnectionToken":"FfF28FINpCYrQKrfBuAOVEiBD0LW3VZVqCiJVr7sZEYvb_FrfG5J3ewWkqDi87pyecsFLpq7hEQrHwNdLnGRsl0pnpnr_I9ajbOhx_zKlEJO8YYVfK-ijEPeWtysYRIT0",
    "ConnectionId":"14250825-344e-4f72-97fd-f52a336e5419",
    "KeepAliveTimeout":20.0,
    "DisconnectTimeout":30.0,
    "TryWebSockets":false,
    "WebSocketServerUrl":null,
    "ProtocolVersion":"1.2"
}
```

Can someone help explain the steps I'm missing to debug and test WebSockets with SignalR?

```
    "TryWebSockets":false,
    "WebSocketServerUrl":null,
```

Comment: Did you upgrade from 4.0 to 4.5?

Comment: Nope... like I said, just created a 4.5 MVC4 WebAPI

Comment: Are you on windows 8 or windows server 2012?

Comment: Windows 7... is that the problem?

Comment: I can drop it on my 2012 iis8 server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebSockets only works on windows 8/Windows Server 2012 + IIS8. Read more about that here http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/supported-platforms